# how to start up s3 ninja programmatically?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to start [s3 ninja](http://s3ninja.net) programmatically to emulate amazon s3. the webpage says to use a script called `sirius.sh` but I was hoping to do it within my java program. Is there anyway to start it up?

Answer (score 0):

According to this, You can achieve this by using `Sirius.start` and `Sirius.stop`.

https://github.com/scireum/s3ninja/issues/16

Comment: So sad to know this... It's a pretty common requirement. How do you achieve integration testing against S3 server with JUnit? Have you found any solution?

Comment: yeah.. tell me about it. I don't know =(